# How to show that for every element $g$ in a Lie group, the curve $\gamma(t) = g\gamma_v(t)$ is an integral curve such that $\gamma(0) = g$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Could anyone help me a little with how to begin to solve the following problem? Thanks in advance!

**Definitions**

> Let $G$ be a Lie group. For $g \in G$, define a diffeomorphism $l_g$ of $G$ by $l_g(h) = gh$. A smooth vector field $X$ is called left-invariant if $(d_hl_g)(X_h) = X_{gh}$ for all $g,h \in G$. Thus, a left-invariant vector field is completely determined by its value at the unit element $e \in G$. It is not difficult to see that every element $v \in T_eG$ arises this way: the corresponding vector field is defined by $X_g^v = (d_el_g)(v)$. Therefore the space of left-invariant vector fields can be identified with the finite dimensional space $\mathfrak g = T_eG$. The commutator of two left-invariant vector fields is again left-invariant. Hence we get a Lie bracket $[\cdot, \cdot]$ on $\mathfrak g: [v,w] = [X^v,X^w]_e$.

**The problem**

For $v \in \mathfrak g$, let $\gamma_v$ be the maximal integral curve of $X^v$ such that $\gamma_v(0) = e$. Show that for every $g \in G$ the curve $\gamma(t) = g\gamma_v(t)$ is an integral curve of $X^v$ such that $\gamma(0) = g$. Conclude that $\gamma_v(t)$ is defined for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and the flow $(\phi^v_t)_t$ defined by $X^v$ is given by $\phi^v_t(g) = g\gamma_v(t)$.

**I can use the following if needed**

Let $X$ be a smooth vector field on a manifold $M$. Suppose there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for every $p \in M$ there is an integral curve $\gamma : (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \rightarrow M$ of $X$ such that $\gamma(0) = p$. Then the maximal integral curves of $X$ are defined on the whole line $\mathbb{R}$.

**What I have so far**

We obviously have that this is true for $e \in G$: $\gamma(t) = e\gamma_v(t) = \gamma_v(t)$. But I don't know what to do for $g \neq e$.

Anyone?

Comment: If your question has been answered you should accept the answer, and/or vote...

Comment: Could you give me the reference for the  result you quote in **I can use the following if needed**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of unwrapping the definitions and using the fact that the tangent map $T$ is functorial:

\begin{align*}\gamma'(t) = (T\gamma)(\partial_s|_t) = T(l_g \circ \gamma_v)(\partial_s|_t) = (Tl_g \circ T\gamma_v)(\partial_s|_t) = Tl_g(X^v_{\gamma_v(t)}) = X^v_{\gamma(t)}.
\end{align*}

You should be able to finish the rest yourself.

Comment: Your $T$, the 'tangent map', what is that?

Comment: $T$ is the functor that assigns to every manifold $M$ it's tangent bundle $TM$, and to every smooth map $f: M \to N$ a vector bundle morphism $Tf: TM \to TN$ along $f$. In some books its action on maps is denoted by $Df$ or $df$ and it might be called the "total derivative of f". Check Loring W. Tu's book for the details, or some other smooth manifolds text.

Comment: So in the notation above, is it the $d_h$? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Essentially yes, but writing $d_h f$ indicates that you are talking about the restriction of $df$ to the fibre above $h$, whereas $df$ has the entire tangent bundle as its domain.